# How is $\beta$ of the $\beta$-Quantile called?

Tags: terminology, quantiles

I was often wondering how to call $\beta$ of the $\beta$-quantile of a distribution. Of course, $\beta$ is a probability or proportion. But is there an official name for it?

So instead of saying "The median equals the $\beta$-quantile with $\beta = 0.5$" we could state "The Median equals the quantile with a xyz of 0.5."

Comment: Maybe just "left tail probability," "area to the left" or something like that.  This isn't a name for the probability, but the *distribution function* is the function $F$ whose value at $\beta$ is equal to the probability you're referring to, at least for continuous distributions.

Comment: It's notionally if not literally a cumulative probability. In some contexts it is also called a plotting position, especially when there is a graph in view or in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

> Maybe just "left tail probability," "area to the left" or something
>   like that. This isn't a name for the probability, but the
>   *distribution function* is the function $F$ whose value at $β$ is equal to the probability you're referring to, at least for continuous
>   distributions.

– dsaxton

It's notionally if not literally a cumulative probability. In some contexts it is also called a *plotting position*, especially when there is a graph in view or in mind. – Nick Cox